# Перевод unix времени в обычную дату. MySQL с PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Есть код:

```
$rows = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `data` ORDER BY time ASC");

while ($row = $rows->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "
        <td>".$row['donate']."</td>
        <td>".$row['nickname']."</td>
        <td>".$row['command']."</td>
        <td>".$row['intid']."</td>
        <td>".$row['amount']."</td>
        <td>".$row['status']."</td>
        <td>".$row['time']."</td>
    </tr>";
}
```

Как мне в последнем столбце `time` вывести обычную дату, если в MySQL идёт `unix` код?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воспользоваться функцией `date()`, например:

```php
date('d.m.Y H:i:s', $row['time']);
```

где первый аргумент — это формат даты, а второй — метка времени unix.

[Подробная информация в документации](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php)

Comment: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'date' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' 
Не помогает

Comment: Надо было сделать `<td>".date('d-m-Y H:i:s', $row['time'])."</td>` , спасибо за помощь